# What is the next normalised floating point number after(before) a normalised floating point number f?

Tags: floating-point

Given a normalized floating point number f what is the next **normalized** floating point number after/before f.

With bit twiddling, extracting mantissa and exponent I have:

```
next_normalized(double&){
      if mantissa is not all ones
          maximally denormalize while maintaining equality 
          add 1 to mantissa
          normalize
      else 
          check overflow
          set mantissa to 1  
          add (mantissa size in bits) to exponent.
      endif
 }
```

But rather than do that can it be done with floating point operations?

As

```
std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()
```

is only an error difference in a "neighborhood" of 1. - e.g.:

```
normalized(d+=std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()) = d for d large
```

it seems more an error ratio than an error difference, thus my naive intuition is

```
(1.+std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon())*f //should be the next.
```

And

```
(1.-std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon())*f //should be the previous.
```

In particular I have 3 questions has anyone done any of the following (for IEEE754):

1)done the error analysis on this issue?

2)proved (or can prove) that for any **normalized** double d

```
    (1.+std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon())*d != d ?
```

3)proved that for any **normalized** double number d no double f exists such that

```
    d < f < (1.+std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon())*d ?
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I’m not sure what you mean by “**normalized** double number”, but getting the next **representable** double number is done with the [`nextafter()` function](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/nextafter.html) in most C standard math libraries.

Comment: I assume as opposed to _denormals_

Comment: nextafter will return the next number - even if that happens to be a denormalized number. The denormalized case isn't so rare - it happens if you call nextafter(0.0, 1.0) - since the next representable number after 0 is a denormalized number (4e-324, when DBL_MIN is 2e-308). Thus you should only use this solution if the first number cannot be zero - or denormalized numbers aren't a problem.

Answer (score 6):

As Robert Kern noted, you want the C nextafter( ) function, or the IEEE754 nextUp( ) and nextDown( ) functions, though those two are not widely implemented just yet.

If you want to avoid nextafter for some reason, you can do:

```
double next = x + scalbn(1.0, ilogb(x) - 52);
```

This adds 2^(exponent of x - 52) to x, which is exactly one unit in the last place (ULP).

If you don't have the usual cmath functions available:

```
double x = 1.0;
uint64_t rep;
assert(sizeof x == sizeof rep);
memcpy(&rep, &x, sizeof x);
rep += 1;
memcpy(&x, &rep, sizeof x);
```

This adds one to the significand of x by operating on the bitwise-representation of the floating-point value; if the next value is in the next binade, this will carry into the exponent, returning the correct value.  If you want it to work for negative values, you'll need to tweak that.

Answer (score 3):

The statement under 3) is false. If d is slightly smaller than 2, then there is exactly 1 floating-point number between d and (1+eps) * d. Here is a program to show it:

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char**)
{
  using namespace std;
  double d = 1.875;
  cout.precision(18);
  cout << "d = " << d << "\n";
  double d2 = (1.+numeric_limits<double>::epsilon())*d;
  cout << "d2 = " << d2 << "\n";
  double f = d + (d2-d)/2;
  cout << "f = " << f << "\n";
}
```

The reason is that (1+eps) * 1.875 equals 1.875 + 1.875 * eps, which is rounded to 1.875 + 2 * eps. However, the difference between consecutive floating-point numbers between 1 and 2 is eps, so there is one floating-point number between 1.875 and 1.875 + 2 * eps, namely 1.875 + eps.

The statement under 2) is true, I think. And Robert Kern probably answered your real question.

Comment: and i might add you have demonstrated that at most 1 such d exists

Comment: What is true with predecessor(predecessor(2)), is also true with any power of two, (1+eps)*(pred(pred(2^i))) != pred(2^i) since they all have same mantissa bit pattern

Comment: Every number in [succ(1.5)*2^k,pred(pred(2))*2^k] is going to be a problem, because first two bits are set, the result will be rounded to upper value, unless you set the rounded mode toward zero

Answer (score 1):

As stated below it turns out after a tiny bit of investigation that for positive floats in intel IEEE754 format of size n-bits  that are < +infinity  treating the concatenated exponent and significand as a n-1 bit unsigned integer adding one gets the next higher and (subtracting one get next lower)

And vice versa if negative. In particular one can interpret the n-1 bit integer as representing the absolute magnitude independent of the sign. And thus when negative one must subtract one to get the next floating point number closer to zero after the negative floating point number f.

Answer (score 0):

1.0 - epsilon is not the predecessor of 1.0, so the negative counter part does not work at all...
The predecessor of 1.0 is 1.0-epsilon/2.0