# How do you find a float's nearest non-equal value?

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-accuracy

A `float` (a.k.a. single) value is a 4-byte value, and supposed to represent any real-valued number. Because of the way it is formatted and the finite number of bytes it is made off, there is a minimum value and a maximum value it can represent, and it has a finite precision, depending on it's own value.

I would like to know if there is a way to get the closest possible value above or below some reference value, given the finite precision of a float. With integers, this is trivial: one simply adds or subtracts 1. But with a `float`, you can't simply add or subtract the minimum float value and expect it to be different from your original value. I.e.

```
float FindNearestSmaller (const float a)
{
    return a - FLT_MIN; /* This doesn't necessarily work */
}
```

In fact, the above will almost never work. In the above case, the return will generally still equal `a`, as the `FLT_MIN` is far beyond the precision of `a`. You can easily try this out for yourself: it works for e.g. `0.0f`, or for very small numbers of order `FLT_MIN`, but not for anything between 0 and 100.

So how would you get the value that is closest but smaller or larger than `a`, given floating point precision?

**Note:** Though i am mainly interested in a C/C++ answer, I assume the answer will be applicable for most programming languages.

Comment: Really curious to see an answer to this.

Comment: `memcpy` into an integer, add one, `memcpy` back into `float` ?

Comment: @BartFriederichs: no, that won't work in all cases.

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/a/7408487

Comment: with float one simply adds one or removes one to the mantissa (and normalizes) to find the next nearest

Comment: There are already [nextafter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter) for you to use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16322465/finding-the-closest-floating-point-value-less-than-a-specific-integer-value-in-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159774/c-next-float-with-numeric-limits-epsilon http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160079/how-to-find-nearest-next-previous-double-value-numeric-limitsepsilon-for-give

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The standard way to find a floating-point value's neighbors is the function `nextafter` for `double` and `nextafterf` for `float`. The second argument gives the direction. Remember that infinities are legal values in IEEE 754 floating-point, so you can very well call `nextafter(x, +1.0/0.0)` to get the value immediately above `x`, and this will work even for `DBL_MAX` (whereas if you wrote `nextafter(x, DBL_MAX)`, it would return `DBL_MAX` when applied for `x == DBL_MAX`).

Two non-standard ways that are sometimes useful are:

1. access the representation of the `float`/`double` as an unsigned integer of the same size, and increment or decrement this integer. The floating-point format was carefully designed so that for positive floats, and respectively for negative floats, the bits of the representation, seen as an integer, evolve monotonously with the represented float.
2. **change the rounding mode to upward**, and add the smallest positive floating-point number. The smallest positive floating-point number is also the smallest increment that there can be between two floats, so this will never skip any float. The smallest positive floating-point number is `FLT_MIN * FLT_EPSILON`.

---

For the sake of completeness, I will add that even without changing the rounding mode from its “to nearest” default, multiplying a float by `(1.0f + FLT_EPSILON)` produces a number that is either the immediate neighbor away from zero, or the neighbor after that. It is probably the cheapest if you already know the sign of the float you wish to increase/decrease and you don't mind that it sometimes does not produce the immediate neighbor. Functions `nextafter` and `nextafterf` are specified in such a way that a [correct implementation](http://opensource.apple.com/source/Libm/Libm-315/Source/Intel/nextafter.s) on the x86 must test for a number of special values and FPU states, and is thus rather costly for what it does.

To go towards zero, multiply by `1.0f - FLT_EPSILON`.

This doesn't work for `0.0f`, obviously, and generally for the smaller denormalized numbers.

The values for which multiplying by `1.0f + FLT_EPSILON` advance by 2 ULPS are just below a power of two, specifically in the interval [0.75 * 2<sup>p</sup> … 2<sup>p</sup>). If you don't mind doing a multiplication and an addition, `x + (x * (FLT_EPSILON * 0.74))` should work for all normal numbers (but still not for zero nor for all the small denormal numbers).

Answer (score 11):

Look at the "nextafter" function, which is part of Standard C (and probably C++, but I didn't check).

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/3/nextafter

Comment: There's a std::nextafter and std::nexttoward starting in c++11.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it out on my machine. And all three approaches:
1. adding with 1 and memcopying
2. adding FLT_EPSILON
3. multiplying by (1.0f + FLT_EPSILON)
seems to give the same answer.

---

**see the result here**
bash-3.2$ cc float_test.c -o float_test; ./float_test 1.023456 10
Original num: 1.023456
int added = 1.023456    01-eps added = 1.023456         mult by 01*(eps+1) = 1.023456
int added = 1.023456    02-eps added = 1.023456         mult by 02*(eps+1) = 1.023456
int added = 1.023456    03-eps added = 1.023456         mult by 03*(eps+1) = 1.023456
int added = 1.023456    04-eps added = 1.023456         mult by 04*(eps+1) = 1.023456
int added = 1.023457    05-eps added = 1.023457         mult by 05*(eps+1) = 1.023457
int added = 1.023457    06-eps added = 1.023457         mult by 06*(eps+1) = 1.023457
int added = 1.023457    07-eps added = 1.023457         mult by 07*(eps+1) = 1.023457
int added = 1.023457    08-eps added = 1.023457         mult by 08*(eps+1) = 1.023457
int added = 1.023457    09-eps added = 1.023457         mult by 09*(eps+1) = 1.023457
int added = 1.023457    10-eps added = 1.023457         mult by 10*(eps+1) = 1.023457

---

**Code**

```
#include <float.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    if(argc != 3) {
        printf("Usage: <binary> <floating_pt_num> <num_iter>\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    float f = atof(argv[1]);
    int count = atoi(argv[2]);

    assert(count > 0);

    int i;
    int num;
    float num_float;

    printf("Original num: %f\n", f);
    for(i=1; i<=count; i++) {
        memcpy(&num, &f, 4);
        num += i;
        memcpy(&num_float, &num, 4);
        printf("int added = %f \t%02d-eps added = %f \tmult by %2d*(eps+1) = %f\n", num_float, i, f + i*FLT_EPSILON, i, f*(1.0f + i*FLT_EPSILON));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `%.9f` is better than `%f` to show what is happening, and `%a` is even better.

Comment: Suggest testing against numbers on just either side of a power-of-2 (and away from 1.0, maybe `-`) like -1023.9 and -1024.1.  Confident significant differences will be shown.

Comment: @chux well that is expected. With larger numbers multiplying by `1+FLT_EPSILON` will give a larger drift. Also the add-by-1 integer method will also affect the mantissa by a larger amount; in some cases like `2^30` changing the exponent as well. But adding by `FLT_EPSILON` still produces consistent results. Actually now the changes are even slower because we are changing bigger numbers; so effect of small `FLT_EPSILON` is shadowed.

Comment: `f + i*FLT_EPSILON` will clearly not work properly for values of `f` larger than 4. No one said that `f*(1.0f + i*FLT_EPSILON)` worked for `i` larger than 1. Interestingly, the `num += i;` method does work for arbitrary values of `i` as long as the float does not overflow.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Actually, `num += i` won't give you the correct answer when the test number gets bigger as I already explained that adding `1` will have a magnified effect on the test number. For instance, with `256` as test number, I get `256.000031` as the next number which can't be correct as there are at least `30` other visible floats in between.

Comment: The next larger `float` after `256.0f` is `256.0000305...f`. [Ref: binary32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) Adding 1 _should_ have a magnified effect as `f` is larger.  Disagree that there are at least 30 visible floats in between.

Comment: "Adding 1" will work for typical `float` ([binary32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)) from `+0.0f` to `FLT_MAX`.

Comment: What makes you think that there are “at least 30 other visible floats” between 256 and 256.000031? What are the bit representations of these floats? What do they print when passed to `printf("%.9e\n", (float) X)`?

Comment: @chux corrected the priting issue. though i the test results were from updated code; so they were correct. BTW can't I declare `float f = 256.00001` ?

Comment: @chux yes you are right... printing `256.000001` prints `256.00000` and printing `256.00002` prints `256.000031`. Thanks for clarifying to me.

Comment: @Nikhil Vidhani Note: Using to `printf("%f", f)` to print the next floating point number is problematic for large and small `float` due to the non-exponential notation and limited number of decimal places.  To get a clearer idea of the nature of the next `float`, use `printf("%.*e", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, f)`.  This will print `FLT_DECIMAL_DIG` digits, guaranteed by the C spec just precise enough to show the difference between any two adjacent `float`s.